# GPG Key import error on yum / dnf / fedup upgrade

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, package-management, dnf

I'm trying to upgrade my system from Fedora 24 to Fedora 25 using `fedup` (actually a shortcut to `dnf system-upgrade`). It fails with some warning about a GPG key.

It offers me to import it, but it fails even if I accept the import.

```
aviso: /var/lib/dnf/system-upgrade/VirtualBox-server-5.1.8-2.fc25.x86_64.rpm: Cabeçalho V4 RSA/SHA1 Signature, ID da chave 6806a9cb: NOKEY
Importando chave GPG 0xB7546F06:
ID de usuário     : "RPM Fusion free repository for Fedora (24) <rpmfusion-buildsys@lists.rpmfusion.org>"
 Impressão digital: 55E7 903B 6087 98E4 EC78 64CD 9F63 8721 B754 6F06
A partir de       : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-25
Correto? [s/N]: n
Os pacotes baixados foram salvos no cache até a próxima transação bem sucedida.
Você pode remover os pacotes em cache executando 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Não instalar nenhuma das chaves
```

Manually importing the key with `gpg --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-25` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

`sudo rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmfusion-free-fedora-25` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should install it instead of importing it. You can use rpm, yum or dnf installers.

Here is the command

```
sudo dnf install https://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/updates/testing/30/Everything/x86_64/Packages/f/fedora-gpg-keys-30-1.noarch.rpm
```