# Update Fedora (25 =>26) Error GPG key install

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm

I try to update Fedora 25 to 26

```
]# dnf system-upgrade download --refresh --releasever=26
```

After uploading packages get a question for add GPG key.

```
попередження: /var/lib/dnf/system-upgrade/kernel-core-4.14.6-200.fc26.x86_64.rpm: Заголовок V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, ід. ключа 64dab85d: NOKEY
Імпортування ключа GPG 0xBFB2D6E3:
 Ід. корист.: «Fedora 26 Primary (26) <fedora-25-primary@fedoraproject.org>»
 Відбиток   : 2D0F 6533 6953 8D2E 6157 F220 AC4F F563 BFB2 D6E3
 Походження : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-26-x86_64
Виконати дію? [y/N]: y
Ключ успішно імпортовано
Імпортування ключів не допомогло, помилкові ключі?
Отримані пакунки було збережено до кешу до наступної успішної дії.
Кешовані пакунки можна вилучити за допомогою команди «dnf clean packages».
Помилка: 


Відкритий ключ для kernel-core-4.14.6-200.fc26.x86_64.rpm не встановленоFailing package is: kernel-core-4.14.6-200.fc26.x86_64
 GPG Keys are configured as: file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-26-x86_64
```

- Open key for kernel-core-4.14.6-200.fc26.x86_64.rpm was not install

I try to this example [GPG Key import error on yum / dnf / fedup upgrade](https://superuser.com/questions/1228860/gpg-key-import-error-on-yum-dnf-fedup-upgrade)

It is not help

```
]# rpm --import etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-26-x86_64
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0x22: 2962/139881839810304
BDB2053 Freeing read locks for locker 0x24: 2962/139881839810304
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't import something that has no content. The proper way to affect this is outlined below:

```bash
cd ~/
wget https://getfedora.org/static/64DAB85D.txt && \
  wget https://getfedora.org/static/3B921D09.txt && \
  rpm --import ~/64DAB85D.txt && \
  rpm --import ~/3B921D09.txt
```

After this the upgrade shall work flawlessly.